# I have 3 carving tools and do not know what they are used for

Tags: hand-tools, tool-identification

[image: enter image[![enter image description here]

Unknown carving tools, wood handles looks like carbon steel blade

Answer (score 1):

You have a set of three contour scraping tools. They can be used for molding, picture frames or any other wood surfacing involving non-flat surfaces. You might use them for paint removal or wood preparation prior to painting, for areas not easily reached with sandpaper.

[image: scraping tool]

Answer (score 0):

What a coincidence, these are the *shave hooks* that I mention in [my Answer posted only yesterday](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/7181/refinishing-how-to-deal-with-streaking-caused-by-a-filler-used-by-a-previous-o/7184#7184).

They're intended to scrape paint and other finishes, usually after it has been softened with chemical stripper or by heat supplied by a blowtorch or heat gun.

Poor-quality ones will be quite blunt and don't work well as supplied. Decent ones have a reasonable edge from the factory but even these can be improved upon if honed to a truly sharp edge by hand. Most modern-day shave hooks are soft enough that sharpening can be accomplished using a file, older ones can be much harder and really need to be honed with the same sorts of things you'd use for a chisel. Yours could be the latter type to judge by the well-made handles.